# Object has different class after archiving/unarchiving

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm working on an Objective-C code base for an iPad project using iOS 6.

After I refactored the name of class 'ClassA' to 'ClassB', I find the following test failing:

```
NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:objectOfClassB];
ServiceOrderOld *decodedObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];

[[[decodedObject class] should] equal:[objectOfClassB class]];
```

The error message I get reads: "[FAILED], expected subject to equal ClassB, got ClassB"

What could be causing this strange behaviour? Any tips on debugging this?

Comment: I'm seeing this too, but only when the class is in a separate static archive from the code being executed. Does that describe your case? Did you ever figure out a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm not too late ;)

I had the same problem while testing a framework.
It turns out that the class in question was also in the test's target. I think it then mismatch (but compile!) with the framework's class.
I removed the class from the test's target and the test passes.

Comment: It's been a while, but if I remember correctly this was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems class is really irrelevant for the archiving mechanism. Did you try just re-casting the class when you unarchive?

```
DesiredClass *object = (DesiredClass*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver
   unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
```

Comment: Problem is that the class has an `isEqual` method containing a class comparison: 

if (!other || ![other isKindOfClass:[self class]]) return NO;

This is now failing. Besides, I'm curious how this is possible. How can objects have the same class name but a different class?

Comment: I do not see this as problem. It is unrelated to archiving.